# How to avoid cross-join to find pairwise distance between each two rows in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, euclidean-distance

I have a spark data frame with 3 columns that indicate positions of atoms i-e Position `X, Y & Z`. Now to find the distance between every 2 atoms for which I need to apply distance formula. The distance formula is `d= sqrt((x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2)`. For the smaller dataset, I was recommended cross-join but for the larger dataset that is very inefficient and time-consuming. Currently, I am using the following piece of code.

```
df = atomsDF.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
windowSpec = W.orderBy("id")
df = df.withColumn("id", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))
df_1 = df.select(*(F.col(col).alias("{}_1".format(col)) for col in df.columns))
df_3 = df_1.crossJoin(df).where("id_1 != id")

df_3 = df_3.withColumn(
        "Distance",
        F.sqrt(
            F.pow(df_3["Position_X_1"] - df_3["Position_X"], F.lit(2))
            + F.pow(df_3["Position_Y_1"] - df_3["Position_Y"], F.lit(2))
            + F.pow(df_3["Position_Z_1"] - df_3["Position_Z"], F.lit(2))
        )
    )
```

My Dataframe look like the following:

```
Position_X|Position_Y|Position_Z|
+----------+----------+----------+
|    27.545|     6.743|    12.111|
|    27.708|     7.543|    13.332|
|    27.640|     9.039|    12.970|
|    26.991|     9.793|    13.693|
|    29.016|     7.166|    14.106|
|    29.286|     8.104|    15.273|
|    28.977|     5.725|    14.603|
|    28.267|     9.456|    11.844|
|    28.290|    10.849|    11.372|
|    26.869|    11.393|    11.161|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Now how can I avoid cross-join because the number of rows grows exponentially after the cross-join? For example, just for the dataset with 3000 rows after the cross join the total number of rows grow to 3000 * 2999 = 8997000 which make it very time-consuming.
Any other Efficient way of finding the pairwise distance between every two rows?

Answer (score 1):

You say that you need to find the distance between every 2 atoms. For this, since the result size is N^2, the run time is by definition quadratic. You can optimize it somewhat, but it will still be quadratic.

You can optimize it only if you don't actually need to find N^2 distances between every 2 atoms, but need to find only pairs based on some criteria.

E.g. commonly one needs to find pairs that are closer than some threshold distance - for this R-trees provide much better scalability. In Spark it might be easier to split atoms into grid of cubes of size equal to threshold distance, then you only need to cross-join between atom and atoms in same or neighboring cubes.

Comment: For applying some threshold on the distance, I still have to find the distance first. Like you mentioned that commonly one needs to find pairs that are closer than some threshold distance. Am I still be doing the cross join and finding the distance. Right?  Will it optimize the results?

Comment: This is the trick - you can filter out a lot of pairs, where you can guarantee the distance between them is greater than the threshold, without actually computing the precise distance between those pairs. Then you only need to compute precise distance between remaining pairs. Look up R-trees in wikipedia, I've also noticed simpler cubical grin in the answer.